# Can't run mvn --version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I installed maven as per http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and I created the following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
M2 : %M2_HOME%\bin
M2_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.0
```

And, I prepended PATH with this:

```
%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

When I try to run `cmd` and enter `mvn --version` it says:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: I ran into this not long ago... Path doesn't support multiple levels of nesting, it'll only evaluate the first layer.  Try setting `M2` to the same value as `M2_HOME` and adding `\bin` to the end

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  It should also be noted that these should be added under "System variables" and not "User variables."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this not long ago... `PATH` doesn't support multiple levels of nesting, it'll only evaluate the first layer. Try setting `M2` to the same value as `M2_HOME` and adding `\bin` to the end